# Roles not getting fetched from database along with the user object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a user registration flow with spring boot (2.1.3.RELEASE) . With the help of few articles I am able to successfully add a user along with its roles and user is able to login into the system. The problem is when user is successfully loged-in, the authentication obect has empty role even when I can see th correct role mapping in mysql database (honestly I am not able to get exactly how roles are fetched from database when findByUserName method is called.
Below is my code:

Entity objects
1. User.java

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public User() {
        //Verification flow 2. set enabled = false
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_unique_number")
    private long id;

    @UniqueUser(groups = UniqueUserOrder.class)
    @Column(name = "username", length = 60,nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.forEach(ur -> authorities.add(new Authority(ur.getRole().getName())));
        return authorities;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    ...//OTHER GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

2. Roles.java

   public class Role

   ```
   {@Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

   public Role() {

   }

   public Role(RolesEnum rolesEnum) {
       this.id = rolesEnum.getId();
       this.name = rolesEnum.getRoleName();
   }


   public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
       return userRoles;
   }

   public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
       this.userRoles = userRoles;
   }

   ...//OTHER GETTERS AND SETTERS }
   ```
3. UserRole.java

   public class UserRole {

   ```
   public UserRole() {}

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   public UserRole(User user, Role role) {
       this.user = user;
       this.role = role;
   }

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User user;


   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
   private Role role;

   ...//OTHER GETTERS AND SETTERS
   ```

   }

4.RolesEnum.java

```
public enum RolesEnum {

    ADMIN(1, "ROLE_ADMIN"),
    BASIC(2, "ROLE_BASIC");

    private final int id;

    private final String roleName;

    ...//OTHER GETTERS AND SETTERS

}
```

New user is getting created as below:

```
...
...
String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(adminPassword);
user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
user.setUsername(adminUsername);
user.setEmail(adminEmail);
user.setUserCreateTime(LocalDateTime.now());

Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
userRole.setUser(user);
userRole.setRole(new Role(RolesEnum.ADMIN));
userRoles.add(userRole);
user.getUserRoles().addAll(userRoles);

user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
user.setEnabled(true);
user.setAccountNonExpired(true);
user.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
user = userRepository.save(user);
...
...
```

At this point user is added successfully along with the roles in database

User is also able to successfully log-in but the problem is after logging, authentication object has an empty list of roles
Below is the code which is failing

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
......
......
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
        return (request, response, **authentication**) -> {
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
             = authentication.getAuthorities();
            for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
                if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                    isAdmin = true;
                    break;
                } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                    isBasic = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

              if (isAdmin) { return "/admin/"; } else if (isBasic) { return
              "/profile.html"; } else { throw new IllegalStateException(); }

            response.sendRedirect("/");
        };
    }
......
......
```

When i inspect authentication object using eclipse the roles are not getting fetched from database
Here is the code for fetching user@Override

```
public User findByUserName(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}
```

Do I need to add some additional logic to fetch roles along with user or Spring handles it behind the scene? Please let me know what I am doing wrong here... Thanks

Comment: i don't really understand the purpose of the "UserRole.class". A ROLE can have many USERS, and a USER can have many ROLES? should you just skip the UserRole class and have a ManyToMany annotation instead?

Comment: Yes, removing user_role class and table, and adding ManyToMany mapping worked. Thanks

Comment: Nice, glad i could help